# Node JS - How to wait until a file exists on Google Cloud Storage Bucket, and then download file

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My team and I have tried numerous methods to solve this problem, but whenever we go to download the file, we get an error stating the file does not exist.

What is the typical way to do this. This seems like something that should be easy,  but I can't seem to find anything that works.

To clarify, my Node JS runs a function that uploads a file to one bucket. This triggers a cloud function which does some processing and then uploads a file to another bucket. I want Node JS to wait for that other file to be uploaded, and then download the file.

```
const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket('receipttext');


async function uploadFile() {
    await storage.bucket("BUCKET_ONE").upload('FILE_PATH', {
        gzip: true,
        metadata: {
            cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
        },
    });
    console.log('step1!');
    const options = {
        destination: 'DOWNLOAD_PATH',
    };

    //Something needs to go here to cause Node JS to wait until the file exists
    let file = null;
    let ifExist = false;
    while(!ifExist) {
        console.log('step1.1!');
        file = await storage
            .bucket("BUCKET_TWO")
            .file('FILE_NAME');
        ifExist =  file.exists();
        //console.log('step1.2!',ifExist);
        console.log('step2!');
    }


    //Downloads the File
    await file.download(options).catch(function(error){
            console.log(2);
        });
    console.log(
        `gs:// downloaded .`
    );
    console.log('step3!');
    let obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('DOWNLOAD_PATH', 'utf8'));
    console.log(obj,"here");

    res.json({response: obj});
}
uploadFile().catch(console.error);
console.log("successUpload");
```

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Notification_Types

Comment: You could try with a cloud function trying triggered by a create event in storage. In that function you can implement the download side. I'm not sure if this fits your actual purpose but is a way to download a file in the moment it is uploaded to a bucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is await keyword as [exists()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#exists) method returns a promise (always true as boolean), which resolves to an array first element of which is the boolean you need.

So I would tweak the line like this:

```
ifExist = (await file.exists())[0]; // (await brackets) needed
```